# Unable to download using NSURLSession from Share Extension on real device

Tags: ios, ios8, nsurlsession

I'm building a Share Extension that needs to download some JSON as a response. I'm completely stumped about why this isn't working, I've tried massaging many little pieces of it and still nothing. On the simulator this works fine.

Here's what I've got:

```
- (void)didSelectPost
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    // ... set up the request

    NSString *const kFLHTTPMethodPOST = @"POST";
    [request setHTTPMethod:kFLHTTPMethodPOST];

    NSString *sessionConfigurationIdentifier = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];

    self.sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:sessionConfigurationIdentifier];
    // The sharedContainerIdentifier must be populated for background sessions
    // https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1
    // http://cl.ly/image/0Y3P1B450U1Y
    self.sessionConfiguration.sharedContainerIdentifier = kFLAppGroupIdentifier;
    // The delegate must be populated for background sessions
    // https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW44
    // http://cl.ly/image/431J0G2r2p0X
    self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:self.sessionConfiguration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];

    // Generate our task and start it

    // Use of a download task is required for extensions even though a data task might be more apt here
    // https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW44
    self.task = [self.session downloadTaskWithRequest:request];
    [self.task resume];

    // Finish the extension

    [self.extensionContext completeRequestReturningItems:nil completionHandler:nil];
}
```

This isn't very different from the sample code at https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW2 and from a lot of the code I've seen elsewhere. Both the main app and the extension have the proper entitlements and provisioning to my knowledge. It seems that the app group is working because the extension is able to store files and pull values from the copy of NSUserDefaults shared with the main app.

Has anybody been able to get this working correctly? Seems like I must be missing something.

**UPDATE:**

Been digging into this further.

I see this logged after the extension finishes.

Aug 28 12:03:41 Tim-Johnsens-iPod nsurlsessiond[98] : Couldn't create directory at file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/4C86E3B4-6795-4D8A-9C47-11B88A252703/Library/Caches/com.apple.nsurlsessiond/Downloads/com.flipboard.flipboard-ipad-debug/, error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 513.)" UserInfo=0x14ea3460 {NSFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/4C86E3B4-6795-4D8A-9C47-11B88A252703/Library/Caches/com.apple.nsurlsessiond/Downloads/com.flipboard.flipboard-ipad-debug, NSUnderlyingError=0x14e7f320 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted"}

The weird part is that I'm already storing files at file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/4C86E3B4-6795-4D8A-9C47-11B88A252703/ successfully, for some reason the NSURLSession can't seem to put files there though.

I added a line to manually create this directory in -viewDidLoad of my extension and that error stopped, however now I'm getting different errors. It looks like a temporary file is being made, but somewhere iOS is creating an invalid URL then my -URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError: on the session is called twice in a row. (Note: Lines starting with "~~" were added by me).

Aug 28 13:33:34 Tim-Johnsens-iPod nsurlsessiond[98] : __NSCFLocalDownloadFile: error 1 creating temp file: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/4C86E3B4-6795-4D8A-9C47-11B88A252703/Library/Caches/com.apple.nsurlsessiond/Downloads/com.flipboard.flipboard-ipad-debug/CFNetworkDownload_BUqFkv.tmp
Aug 28 13:33:34 Tim-Johnsens-iPod nsurlsessiond[98] :  connection from pid 502: Warning: Exception caught during invocation of received message, dropping incoming message and invalidating the connection.
    Exception: *** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter
Aug 28 13:33:34 Tim-Johnsens-iPod ShareExtension[502] : ~~ -[FLShareExtensionViewController URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:] - Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1 "unknown error" UserInfo=0x176d19d0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=[REDACTED], NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=[REDACTED], NSLocalizedDescription=unknown error}
Aug 28 13:33:34 Tim-Johnsens-iPod ShareExtension[502] : ~~ -[FLShareExtensionViewController URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:] - Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-997 "Lost connection to background transfer service" UserInfo=0x1765fb80 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=[REDACTED], NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=[REDACTED], NSLocalizedDescription=Lost connection to background transfer service}

I'm guessing my extension is getting the callback with the "Lost connection to background transfer service" error because the background transfer service crashed due to that exception being thrown.

Comment: Also asked this on the dev forums and opened a radar for it. https://devforums.apple.com/message/1031240#1031240

Comment: When building a basic sample app I get the same result.

Comment: A couple more things, when I use a GET request instead of POST I get the same result (the request is never sent). Apple says you can use POST requests for download tasks.

Comment: have you add shared identifier to **App Group** in **Capabilities** for your container app and extension Targets's Setting?  https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW6

Comment: @c0ming yes, if I didn't do that it wouldn't even work in the simulator.

Comment: Did you fixed this problem? I'm having a similar situation where I cannot perform a POST request.

Comment: It appears that this was resolved in the GM.

Comment: I'm seeing something similar. My task completes successfully in the background, but when I foreground the extension it reports it as a failure and delivers the same error (lost connection to background service).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was fixed in the iOS 8 GM, it was a bug in betas only.